# Regular expression that excludes some

Tags: regex, matlab

I would like to write a regular expression (I am using MATLAB) that would find the sequence 'a' but reject cases in which the whole string contains the isolated character 'x', i.e. ' x ' (including the space) where 'x' is used as a separator for a and b).

Here are few examples that I can think of.

- 'a'     : match 'a'.
- 'a b'   : match 'a'.
- 'b a'   : match 'a'.
- 'a x b' : don't match 'a' (because a and b are separated by x).
- 'b x a' : don't match 'a' (because b and a are separated by x)
- 'a xb'  : match 'a' (because xb is not the same as the isolated character x used to separate words).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fun question. I'll add a few test cases which I think are necessary to make the problem well specified. Hopefully this is what you intended.

**Test data**:

```
s = {'a', ... %// match
    'a b', ... %// match
    'b a', ... %// match 
    'a x b', ... %// don't
    'b x a', ... %// don't
    'a xb', ... %// match
    'ab', ... %// don't match
    'ba' ... %// don't match
    } ;
```

**Regular expression**:

```
ind = cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(regexp(x,'^a(?=\s)|(?<=\s)a$|^a$|(?<=\s)(a)(?=\s)')),s) ...
& cellfun(@(x) isempty(regexp(x,'(?<=\s)x(?=\s)')),s)

ind =

     1     1     1     0     0     1     0     0

>> s(ind)

ans = 

    'a'    'a b'    'b a'    'a xb'
```

**Explanation**:

Look for strings containing `x` where the match is preceded by a space (`(?<=\s)`) and followed by a space (`(?=\s)`. Exclude these.

Look for strings which either begin with an `a` followed by a space (`^a(?=\s)`), or which end in `a` and are preceded by a space (`(?<=\s)a$`), or which are exactly `a` with no other characters (`^a$`), or which contain `a` both preceded and followed by a space (`(?<=\s)(a)(?=\s)`). Match these.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Let's borrow @transversality condition's test cases and add a few extras:

```
s = {'a', ... %// match
    'a b', ... %// match
    'b a', ... %// match 
    'a x b', ... %// don't
    'b x a', ... %// don't
    'a xb', ... %// match
    'ab', ... %// don't match
    'ba', ... %// don't match
    'x a', ... %// don't match
    'a x' ... %// don't match
    } ;
```

This solution does not use lookarounds at all. Instead, it uses [anchors](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html#f0-42983):

```
ind = cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(regexp(x, '\<a\>', 'once')), s) ...
    & cellfun(@(x) isempty(regexp(x,'\<x\>', 'once')), s)
```

This just finds strings containing `a`, where `a` is both at beginning and end of word (and a word is a contiguous sequence of alphanumerical characters), and not containing an isolated `x`.

In contrast to @tc's test, the last two cases don't match with this test (but maybe they should? OP hasn't specified ...).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Matlab then you have better alternatives than regex. But if you insist, you can use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!.\bx\b.)a(?!.\bx\b.)
```

Comment: `regexp('a x b','(?<!.\bx\b.)a(?!.\bx\b.)')` gives `1` (i.e. matches `a`). Perhaps `'(?<! x )a(?! x )'` ?

Comment: @LuisMendo that will match `x a v` for example, which is not good.

Comment: Hm, actually I think I don't understand the question